# Date и Time picker на андроид.

Tags: android, java

Доброй ночи!
Вопрос: Имеется поле ввода, при расположении курсора на нем, необходимо чтобы вышло диологовое окно с возможностью ввода даты и времени, и так чтобы это выглядело одинаково(в плане дизайна)?

Знаю, что надо использовать date и time picker, но не знаю кк их объеденить!

Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте использовать диалог, но укажите ему layout, в котором расположите DatePicker и TimePicker.

Answer (score 1):

думаю, Вам поможет [эта ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14888908/1233682)